# ValueError: Unrecognized backend string 'gtkagg': valid strings are ['GTK3Agg',

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model 
import pandas as pd
```

```
ValueError: Unrecognized backend string 'gtkagg': valid strings are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'Qt4Agg', 'Qt4Cairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but to solve the problem, do what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 0):

The backend you specified does not exist on your machine. You can use one of the backends suggested in error message like `GTK3Agg`.